# Servlet mapping - unable to access my resources (css & js)

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, netbeans

I'm very confused with servlet mapping. From what i understand

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

is that all xx.htm will go into this servlet.

I have no problem accessing these 2 web page (able to retrieve css & js)

```
http://localhost:8080/smartcoursesystem/university.htm
http://localhost:8080/smartcoursesystem/home.htm
```

The problem is when i go to this path

```
http://localhost:8080/smartcoursesystem/university/edit.htm
```

At this page, all my resource(css & js) are missing. What is the problem?

My dispatcher servlet

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/university")
public class universityController {

public static String entity_name = "University";

@RequestMapping()
public String getAll(Model m){

    universityModel model = new universityModel();
    univCrsModel uc = new univCrsModel();
    m.addAttribute("univList", model.getAll());
    m.addAttribute("entity", entity_name);
    m.addAttribute("countUniv", model.countUniv());        

    return "all";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String edit(@RequestParam(value="id") int id, Model m){

    universityModel model = new universityModel();        
    m.addAttribute("univ", model.getUniv(id));
    m.addAttribute("entity", entity_name);

    return "edit";
}
```

edit.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Edit University Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="/assets/images/icon-128x128.png" alt="smart course">
        //more code
    </body>
</htm>
```

I have tried change my url-pattern to "/ " but doesn't help. In fact, changing url-pattern to "/" make my welcome file not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have put all the jsp files in **WEB-INF**,so all your jsp pages can only be access via springMVC request,it can't be accessed directly,the **js** and **css** files also can't be accessed.

As you know **js** and **css** are static files,they don't have need to be accessed via springMVC request,so you can let them exclude from the *viewResolver*,just add the code below to you *web.xml* and redeploy your applicaiton,then it will works!

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply...I'm getting this error after i add the code above to web.xml `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no web component by the name of default here.`. Do i need to create a servlet name default?

Comment: @McSam no,the *default* is a reserved servlet,can you show me snippet of your web.xml? you can also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505321/error-occurred-during-glassfish-deployment-there-is-no-web-component-by-the-na

Comment: all the code in my web.xml is already shown in my question. For your information I'm not using maven.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by replacing

```
<img src="/assets/images/icon-128x128.png" alt="smart course">
```

to

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="context" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" /> 
<img src="${context}/assets/images/icon-128x128.png" alt="smart course">
```

Thanks for the kind answer